# I changed Frontend language and the frontend changed

Tags: magento-1.9, css, frontend, localisation

I have changed the front-end language, Now my site looks different. It seems that the css is lost..
How can I change the language without loosing my style of front-end ?

Comment: Clear your cache

Comment: what udr magento version?

Comment: Im using version 1.9

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, static view files like the CSS are generated per theme **and** locale.

Let's say you switched to `de_DE`, then you need to generate the files with

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

Documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

If you set your system to developer mode, you should not need to do this manually.

Comment: do you sure this magento 2.X question?

Comment: 99%. Why would this happen in Magento 1?

Comment: soo confident #fabian ...ha ha

Comment: im using version 1.9

Comment: Interesting. Then my answer does not apply to you